# Disabling SELinux in Android 5.0.1

Tags: selinux, android-framework

I am trying to identify the configuration file where SELinux is set to Enforcing mode in Android Framework.

Please do not reply just saying

```
adb shell su 0 setenforce permissive
```

I need the system to boot in permissive mode or have SELinux completely disabled at boot time.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two ways that enforcing mode is set. On user builds, it will always be in enforcing. On eng or userdebug, you can control it. You can control it in the standard selinux way, by setting enforcing=1/0 on the kernel command line as outlined in Dan Walsh's blog:

http://danwalsh.livejournal.com/10972.html

The Android centric way is to set the kernel command line to androidboot.selinux=permissive

You can control the kernel command line by editing your BoardConfig.mk and adding this:

```
BOARD_KERNEL_CMDLINE += androidboot.selinux=permissive
```

The Android centric way is enforced by init, if you look in system/core/init/init.cpp look at the selinux_initialize() routine that is called from main().

Comment: Therefore there is no way to disable selinux in user build, isn't there?

Comment: I'm building for the emulator (lunch aosp_arm-eng). Which BoardConfig.mk should I be editing?