# How to disable SELinux competely in android

Tags: android, selinux

For some really unavoidable circumstances, I want to completely disable `SEAndroid` from my `Android builds` and not  just making it `permissive`. Any help would be greatly appreaciated. But please dont answer in a way that "Instead you can make it `permissive`", because I know that but I simply want to disable it in my case.
I have already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29243105/disabling-selinux-in-android-5-0-1) post, but it was not what I was looking for!

Comment: It seems very odd you would want to completly disable SeAndroid. Could you elavorate why ?

Comment: Because of Samsung's forced enfocing policies, and no git commits in their kenel sources and hence the kernel can't be made perfectly permissive (just by reverting commits). And I am trying to boot custom ROM on my device and through the logs, I came to know that inspite of being permissive, it is still not giving permissions

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try editing the default AOSP SE-policy to allow access **to** all **for** all. Start by deleting all the "neverallow" rules from all the '.te' files, and work your way by finding all the various domains on the system, and granting each and every one of them permissions to all resources on the device (files, dirs, sockets, etc).

This might take some work, but you will eventually get an enforced SE-Policy that permits everything.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it seems preety good step, but I am preety much sure that we can also disable it just by doing some tweaks in the kernel sources.. Your method is also good, although